# Unable to load 3D object using three.js in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, three.js, 3d

I am trying to load a 3D object in my react app using the three.js library. I have successfully integrated the three.js in my code as I have not received any warnings or errors when trying to load the object files which are of type .obj and .mtl files. I am clueless about what is going wrong as there are no errors or warnings on the console but the object is not being displayed. I have attached the relevant code of the same,

```
import React from 'react';
import './css/ModelView.scss';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js';
import { MTLLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/MTLLoader.js';
import { ColladaLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/ColladaLoader.js';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js'


class ModelView extends React.Component {
    loadGeoreferencingOffset = (cb) => {
        const geoFile = `/3d/119/coords.txt`;
        console.log("geofile found ", geoFile)
        cb = ({x: 0, y: 0});
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.toggleTexturedModel();
        this.loadCameras();
        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
        document.getElementById('model-view').appendChild(renderer.domElement)
    }

    loadCameras() {
        function getMatrix(translation, rotation, scale) {
            var axis = new THREE.Vector3(-rotation[0],
                -rotation[1],
                -rotation[2]);
            var angle = axis.length();
            axis.normalize();
            var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(axis, angle);
            matrix.setPosition(new THREE.Vector3(translation[0], translation[1], translation[2]));

            if (scale != 1.0) {
                matrix.scale(new THREE.Vector3(scale, scale, scale));
            }

            return matrix.transpose();
        }

        const colladaLoader = new ColladaLoader();
        const fileloader = new THREE.FileLoader();
        const scene = new THREE.Scene()
        colladaLoader.load('/components/camera.dae', (collada) => {
            const dae = collada.scene;

            fileloader.load(`/3d/119/shots.geojson`, (data) => {
                console.log("camera loaded", data)
                const geojson = JSON.parse(data);
                const cameraObj = dae.children[0];
                cameraObj.material.forEach(m => {
                    m.transparent = true;
                    m.opacity = 0.7;
                });

                let i = 0;
                geojson.features.forEach(feat => {
                    const material = cameraObj.material.map(m => m.clone());
                    const cameraMesh = new THREE.Mesh(cameraObj.geometry, material);
                    cameraMesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
                    let scale = 1.0;

                    cameraMesh.matrix.set(...getMatrix(feat.properties.translation, feat.properties.rotation, scale).elements);

                    scene.add(cameraMesh);

                    cameraMesh._feat = feat;
                    this.cameraMeshes.push(cameraMesh);

                    i++;
                });
            }, undefined, console.error);
        });
    }


    toggleTexturedModel() {
        const mtlLoader = new MTLLoader();
        mtlLoader.load(`/3d/119/ortho.mtl`, (materials) => {
            materials.preload();

            const objLoader = new OBJLoader();

            objLoader.load(`/3d/119/ortho.obj`, (object) => {
                this.loadGeoreferencingOffset((offset) => {
                    object.translateX(offset.x);
                    object.translateY(offset.y);
                    this.modelReference = object;
                    this.setState({
                        initializingModel: false,
                    });
                });
            });
        });

    }

    // React render
    render() {
        return (<div id='model-view' className="model-view">  </div>);
    }
}

export default ModelView;
```

Comment: Are you sure that the files you are trying to load are reachable?

Comment: Check asynchronous code too, maybe you are trying to perform some action without waiting another action to complete.

Comment: yes, all files trying to load are exist and reachable.